# Tailwind with dynamic values

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, tailwind-css

I am learning tailwind in react and want to put dynamic value into css using tailwind. 
I am used to MUI and there its quite simple like

```
<Box sx={{ width: dynamicValue }} />
```

How do I do such thing in tailwind ?
And if I cannot do that with tailwind why in MUI its not a problem ?

Comment: This question has been answered many times. See: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Btailwind-css%5D+dynamic and the official docs https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names

Answer (score 1):

My Answer:

Tailwind CSS provides numeric and fraction values.

For example.

```
w-0 width: 0px;
w-px    width: 1px;
w-0.5   width: 0.125rem; /* 2px */
w-1 width: 0.25rem; /* 4px */
w-1.5   width: 0.375rem; /* 6px */
...

w-auto  width: auto;
w-1/2   width: 50%;
w-1/3   width: 33.333333%;
w-2/3   width: 66.666667%;
```

Also, you can use custom width size as like below.

```
w-[619px]  or w-[50%]
```

Please refer to this link.
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/width

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<div style={{ width: `${widthValue}px` }}></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to stylize your Material components with tailwind you must first change the injection order of the styles. Once is done you can just simply add the `classname` prop and start typing the styles you want

For this case:

```
<Box sx={{ width: dynamicValue }} />
```

you can do:

```
<Box classname={`${dynamicValue}`} />
```

Keep in mind that the `${}` is use to add a variable inside the styles and the `` are used to allow the variable inside